# OneLogin and private credentials

Tags: saml, onelogin

Is OneLogin (https://www.onelogin.com/) able to provide SSO but have the Identity provider interrogate a db of credentials that are held privately by the customer of OneLogin? i.e. Our company sign up with OneLogin and provide some sort of secure REST API that will be used, by OneLogin, to authenticate, using our private DB of user credentials?
Thanks
M

Comment: I guess question is asked in wrong forum. You should rather drop a mail to onelogin support team regarding this.

Comment: Currently you can user Active Directory, LDAP and HRMS systems as Authentication Directories in OneLogin. You can implement your Identity Provider using SAML/OIDC which then uses your Database as authentication provider. Other than this there is no way you can use Database as Authentication Provider directly with OneLogin

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to implement your own Trusted Identity provider (that uses your database for credentials), OneLogin could be configured to defer to that.

Beyond that, you'd have to wait for OL to support Databases as Authentication directories.